# Gitlab CI: PreLoad database with data

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to reload the test database with data using a dump.

The idea is the prefill postgres:14.1 with the dump, before running the test.

So far, I have the following .gitlab-ci.yml but the DB can't file the dump file.

```
image: "custom_image:latest"
services:
  - "postgres:14.1"

variables:
  RAILS_ENV: test
  POSTGRES_DB: test
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  PGPASSWORD: postgres
  POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/test"

pg_restore:
  stage: build
  image: postgres:14.1
  script:
    - pg_restore --version
    - pg_restore --no-privileges --no-owner --dbname=postgresql://postgres:postgres@0.0.0.0:5432/test db/test.dump
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./db

test:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - pg_restore
  script:
    - bundle exec rake db:migrate
    - bundle exec rake test
```

Comment: Hello! Could you add an more elaborate description of the error?
E.g. A print screen of the error

Answer (score 0):

> --dbname=postgresql://postgres:postgres@0.0.0.0:5432/test

In the case where you use `services:` the database is not on localhost. So `0.0.0.0` is not the correct host to use here. Instead, it will be the hostname `postgres`. The `DATABASE_URL` is the value you want to use instead. `postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/test`

You can also define an explicit hostname alias:

```yaml
services:
  - name: "postgres:14.1"
    alias: mydatabasehostname
```

Additionally, services are ephemeral and do not carry state between jobs. So your `test:` job won't see any changes made to the database in any other job. You must setup the DB in every job.